# Appium ios automation not going forward

Tags: appium-ios

I am try to use appium to launch my application but it keep in "[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723",does anybody meet the same issue before?

My ios settings(used a simulator):

[image]

```html
Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --debug-log-spacing --platform-version "9.3" --platform-name "iOS" --app "/Users/xualvin/Desktop/AnPoker.app" --show-ios-log --device-name "iPhone 6s Plus"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:

[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'iPhone 6s Plus'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/xualvin/Desktop/AnPoker.app'
[Appium]   showIOSLog: true
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"iOS"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"9.3"}'
[Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities '{"deviceName":"iPhone 6s Plus"}'
[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/Users/xualvin/Desktop/AnPoker.app"}'
[Appium]   --show-ios-log => --default-capabilities '{"showIOSLog":true}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:

[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'iPhone 6s Plus'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/xualvin/Desktop/AnPoker.app'
[Appium]   showIOSLog: true

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Comment: It works after I change the IP to 127.0.0.1 in Appium configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Now the updated version is Appium 1.6.3 which don't have any UI,

You can download a utility from below link to inspect the elements using 1.6.3
https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector